# Parsing strings into data frames

Tags: r, parsing

I have a bunch of strings which look like this:

```
 [3] "  3. Wiki: Los Angeles 3:58pm; score:1.959502"        
 [4] "  4. Wiki: Boston 6:58pm; score:1.959502"             
 [5] "  5. Disambiguation: 'Boon; score:1.934644"            
 [6] "  6. Wiki: The Note (album)\"; score:1.786931"
```

I parse them into a data frame like this:

```
read.csv(text=sub("^  [0-9]*\\. (Wiki|Disambiguation): (.*); score:([0-9\\.]*)$","\"\\2\",\\3",ll),
         header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

the trouble is that the `\\2` text which I enclose in quotes may contains quotes (double and single) itself.

How do I deal with this?

Comment: does changing the double to single in `,"\"\\2\",` to `,"\'\\2\'` help? the sub still works `sub("^  [0-9]*\\. (Wiki|Disambiguation): (.*); score:([0-9\\.]*)$","\'\'\'''2''\',\\3", 'hello')
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the double quotes:

```
ll <-  gsub('"', '', ll)
```

NOTE: Changed answer after poster gave an example of how it goes wrong.

Comment: I added quotes to the places where they cause me grief